# Convergence of the infinite series $\sum_{n\in\text{odd}}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, mathematical-physics, electromagnetism

This is a follow-up on a previous question I have asked, but since I have made some improvements, I wanted to make a new post.

I was studying 'Introduction to Electromagnetism' by David Griffiths and during his derivation of the solution to Laplace's equation in ch. 3.3, he states that the following relation is true (See eq. 3.36-3.37).

$V(x,y)=\frac{4 V_0}{\pi} \sum_{n=1,3,5...} \left[\frac{1}{n}\text{e}^{-\frac{n \pi x}{a}} \text{sin}\left(\frac{n \pi y}{a}\right) \right]=\frac{2 V_0}{\pi} \text{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{\text{sin}(\frac{\pi y}{a})}{\text{sinh}(\frac{\pi x}{a})}\right)\tag{1}$

I want to show that this relation is true. We see that;

$\sum_{n=1,3,5...} \left[\frac{1}{n}\text{e}^{-\frac{n \pi x}{a}} \text{sin}\left(\frac{n \pi y}{a}\right) \right]=\frac{1}{2} \text{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{\text{sin}(\frac{\pi y}{a})}{\text{sinh}(\frac{\pi x}{a})}\right)\tag{2}$

Now, the left-hand side of (2) can be rewritten as

$\text{Im} \left(\sum_{\text{n odd}}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)$, where $z=\text{e}^{\frac{\pi(-x+iy)}{a}}$

Because

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \operatorname{Im}\left(\sum_{\text{n odd}} \frac{e^{n \pi (-x+i y) / a}}{n}\right)=\operatorname{Im}\left(\sum_{\text{n odd}} \frac{e^{-n{\pi x / a}} e^{n \pi i y/a}}{n}\right) \\
& =\operatorname{Im}\left(\sum_{n \text { odd }} \frac{e^{-n \pi x/ a} \cos (n \pi y/a)+i e^{-n \pi x / a} \sin (n \pi y/a.}{n}\right) \\
& =\sum_{\text{n odd}} \frac{e^{-n \pi x/a} \sin (n \pi y / a)}{n} \\
&
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

So essentially the problem can be expressed as determining the convergence of $ \left(\sum_{\text{n odd}}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}\right)$ and then take the imaginary part.

I have used the ratio test to show that this relation actually converges, but how do I determine to what value the series converges and ultimately show that (1) is true?

Comment: What about power series convergence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_1(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}=-\ln(1-z),~~~~~~~~S_2(z)=\sum_{n\in\text{odd}}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}$$

First note above two series are absolute convergent for $|z|<1$, hence rearrangement doesn't change the value that they are convergent to.

$$S_2(z)=S_1(z)-\sum_{n\in\text{even}}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}=S_1(z)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{2k}=S_1(z)-\frac12S_1(z^2)$$

hence

$$S_2(z)=-\ln(1-z)+\frac12\ln(1-z^2)=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right),~~~~-1<z<1$$

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a very smart and beautiful derivation. I tried something similar using $\text{S}_2(z)=\text{S}_1(z)-\sum_{\text{n even}}\frac{z^n}{n}$, but I did not realize these clever reformulations that you present.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, that's the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n\,\text{odd}} \frac{z^n}{n} = \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2p+1}}{2p+1} = \tanh^{-1}(z)$$

Comment: Maybe give him a hint to get this result?

Comment: That you for your answer. I understand the first equality, but why is it true that $\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2p+1}}{2p+1} = \text{tanh}^{-1}(z)$?

Comment: It is a well known result. You can take a look at this link to have more details https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions

Comment: Thank you very much. I see that this is a well-defined series expansion.

Comment: Okay; last question. Now that I know we have $\text{tanh}^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{2}\text{ln}\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$, how do I determine the imaginary part of this quantity?

Comment: Take a look at principal value of the complex logarithm function https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: Hmm, okay I see that $\text{Im}[\text{ln}(z)]=\text{Im}[\text{ln}(x+iy)]=\text{atan2}(y,x)=\text{tan}^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$, but in our case we have $\text{ln}\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$. I can split the natural logarithm into $\text{ln}(1+z)-\text{ln}(1-z)$ and take the imaginary part of both terms, but then I end up with the sum of two arctan-terms. Can you perhaps guide me to a suitable approach?

Comment: This is treading into new question territory at this point, Rasmus.

Comment: I have now completely solved the exercise. I used an inverse tangential rule for the last part. Thank you all!